# Is MEF a replacement for System.Addin?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, mef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)

Is the Managed Extensibility Framework a replacement for System.Addin? Or are they complementary?

Comment: +1 for this question. How come the answerers didn't touch on whether there is overlap (and what that is) between the two technologies?   
For instance MSFT:Alex Bulankou offers this quote,   
"Well, I'd say we probably would like to be positioned as a more generic higher level component model for both modular applications AND external add-ins. AS of this CTP however, MEF does not yet offer a story for versioning and isolation and it does not offer a concrete scenario how MEF can integrate with MAF to obtain this isolation support."

Comment: @cdiggins: please don't vote to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer question.  For one thing, that stops two questions both being closed as duplicates of one another; secondly, this question wasn't a duplicate when it was first asked.  Closing a question as a duplicate tells the asker that they should have searched a bit harder for an answer to their question.  When Chris Sutton posted this question, the question you linked to didn't exist and so Chris cannot be accused of not trying hard enough to find it.  If it bothers you that much, vote to close the other question as a dupe.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: What you say makes sense, however there are other ways to rationalize it. I don't necessarily agree that closing a question as a duplicate is in fact saying anything of the kind to Chris Sutton. To be honest I try to ignore past history and make choices that make  StackOverflow.com as good as possible today and tomorrow. Anyway, it is a democratic process, and I'm glad you are presenting an argument to keep the question open and close the other one.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I notice you didn't vote to close the other question, why not?

Comment: @cdiggins: firstly, the message in the closure banner below does specifically mention 'earlier questions'.  Secondly, I'm not convinced that the two questions are duplicates.  Perhaps if I knew more about the technologies involved I would be more able to say whether they were duplicates.  As I didn't feel informed enough to make a decision, I chose not to vote to close either question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is touched in the MSDN Forums here:

[Comparison to the AddIn libraries?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/MEFramework/thread/cf6b7cbc-1123-4b32-9810-c235d9606b66)

And also by Krzysztof Cwalina in his blog on the release of MEF:

[Managed Extensibility Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2008/04/25/MEF.aspx)

**Summary**: they live side by side.

Answer (score 14):

Short answer no it is not. System.Addin allows you to isolate add-ins in to a seprate app-domain / process. It also provides facilities for versioning. These capabilities are critical for many customers particularly large ISVs. MEF on the other hand is designed to be simple programming model for extensibility. The two can work together and complement each other.

Answer (score 2):

.. just two links for further reference:

- [SO question: Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)
- [Kent Boogaart blog: MAF and MEF](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/02/maf-and-mef.html)

Comment: The Kent Boogaart blog link is dead. His new blog appears to be here http://kent-boogaart.com/, but I'm not sure to which post this answer is referring.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, some time ago I developed so called IsolatingCatalog, which is MEF catalog for providing part isolation. You can instruct it so that you parts are created in a separate app domain/process. WCF is used for IPC. Check it out [here](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/07/isolating-mef-components.html).