# Are there any articles/examples of using System.AddIn with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, assemblies, plugins, system.addin

Does anyone know about any articles/examples of using System.AddIn with ASP.NET and/or ASP.NET MVC applications?

I'm looking to use System.AddIn to make an ASP.NET MVC application extensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples I have seen all use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF).

> The Managed Extensibility Framework
>   (MEF) is a new library in .NET that
>   enables greater reuse of applications
>   and components. Using MEF, .NET
>   applications can make the shift from
>   being statically compiled to
>   dynamically composed.

See also [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)