# Asp.net 2.0 website design for all isoleted module?

Tags: asp.net, web

Is it possible to refactor a website in such a way all modules are separate and if we need to change one module then we can modify that single module part and deploy it . During deployment we should require only to re-publish for an module and update the site on the server. If this is feasible with help of other versions by utilizing other improved features, please let me know.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what a "module" is. ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms does not have any built-in functionality or services to logically separate a web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load modules dynamically in the application, [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) is a good solution for .NET projects. This will let you add/remove modules at runtime, but you will need to define what a module is.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a plug-in based system, so that your host application loads all plugins to gain access to functionality but updates to each individual plugins can be managed independently of the host application.

Have a look at this thread which contains some links...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743383/1538039

I haven't looked at the Orchard project, but Umbraco and NopCommerce both implement plug in based architecture.

This will definitely add a layer of complexity to your application, but can be useful if you want other developers to be able to functionality for your application