# CodeDomProvider: Is it possible to unload compiled code

Tags: .net

.NET application I work on allows to extend it's functionality with C# scripts that are put into configuration file and compiled like that:

```
CodeDomProvider provider;
...
var result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(prms, new[] { scriptCode });
var asm = result.CompiledAssembly;
var t = asm.GetType("ScriptClass");
var scriptInstance = (IScript)Activator.CreateInstance();
```

I have to allow users to change configuration file, catch this event and recompile scripts in runtime without application restart.

I'm warned that previous code will still utilize memory. How should I unload compiled code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do this is to load it into a separate `AppDomain` and kill the entire `AppDomain`. I imagine this means moving much of the code related to *compiling* it to the second `AppDomain`, too. Then the question becomes how to talk cross-`AppDomain`; there, implicit remoting is IMO the easiest option.

Comment: Thank you @Marc, I'll investigate this option

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll have to use different AppDomains, you should have a look at the System.Addin namespace. It eases extensibility. A full discussion on SO is available here: [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)

Comment: Thank you @Simon. The discussion you point me at covers the problem more generally.