# Microsoft add-In with .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, maf

I am extending an application using [MAF](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9396/creating-extensible-applications-with-maf/) in .net framework. I have implemented a pipeline and the required folder structure and it is working fine when I have the add-in implemented in one dll.

If I have a complex add-in where one dll implements the contract and a supporting dll performs the internal logic.

When I build this add-in project then the main dll and the supporting dlls are copied to the add-in folder and at that time the framework is not able to find the token from that folder.

Comment: @alexn, No - MAF is different. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin

Comment: @vcsjones Wow, never heard of that. Strange!

Comment: Maybe some code samples might help understand where you might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the supporting assemblies into the GAC because the pipeline domains aren't able to resolve external dependencies from within the pipeline folders.  Some of the interfaces in System.AddIn.Contract seem like they might be targeted for a scenario like you describe (IServiceProvider and IProfferServiceContract), but there are zero examples from Microsoft on how to use them.

It's a real shame that Microsoft has been so completely silent on MAF for the last two years.  The lack of complex real-world examples is a big hindrance given the complexity of using it.  The silence is deafening...

Comment: @ bradmo Hi!, It seems like you have a lot of experience with MAF. I'd like to contact you. BTW, I know is not a good practice try to contact enother user this way, but I need help. Thanks.