# Patterns for plugin architecture

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, design-patterns

I am trying architect a big project which using Entity Framework. It's extendable application. I need to create some BLL, which I can use from Api controllers, Web controllers and another modules.
I need to provide access to the db entities. But I want to control and add some logic for any changes of them.
And I don't know which is the best way to implement it.
Maybe I need to create some class such as controllers or to create proxies/wrappers for entities.
Are there some patterns I can use?

Comment: Designing application questions are out of scope for SO. Please try to make your question more concrete...

Comment: If you want a ready-made plugin architecture, use MEF or MAF. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/) But as Alexei points out, this question is a bad fit for StackOverflow. Try to post questions about *actual code*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to use MEF. It is powerful framework for extensible applications.
http://mef.codeplex.com/