# How to call/Invoke a VSTO generated addin(DLL) from an EXE

Tags: c#, com, vsto, add-in

I have created a VSTO Word Addin. It has generated a DLL file. I don't want to deploy that as an EXE. But I want to use a C# application(EXE) to call or invoke this VSTO dll. Is this possible? If possible how do I implement?

Please note that I don't want to deploy my Addin as an EXE. I only want my VSTO addin to remain as a DLL and then to be called from an EXE.

I have tried the below approach with no luck.

```
1) WordAddIn.ThisAddIn addin = new WordAddIn.ThisAddIn(null, null);
```

Here the WordAddin is the VSTO dll.

```
2) Using Reflection
Assembly newAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:...bin\\Debug\\WordAddin.dll");

Type[] types = newAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
Type entryType = newAssembly.GetType("ThisAddin");
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(types[0], true);
```

I get 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.' in this case.

Unable to go further!. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Very hard to see the point, VSTO was designed to make it easy to write add-ins for Office programs.  So that the Office program can use your code.  If you want to write a class library that you call from your *own* EXE then there's just no point whatsoever in using VSTO.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO is for purely for customizing MS Office via add-ins; there is no sane way to use this with your .Net exe.  For extending your own .Net exe with add-ins see the following resources:

- [the MSDN article on .Net Add-ins and Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx)
- The SO question on [the .Net Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) vs. the .Net Managed AddIn Framework (MAF, aka System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)
- [Kent Boogaart's blog on MAF and MEF](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/02/maf-and-mef.html)