# System.AddIn vs System.ComponentModel.Composition

Tags: .net, plugins, add-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)

What are the differences between the import and export functionality of the System.ComponentModel.Composition namespace vs the addin functionality of the System.AddIn namespace?  Looks like there is some functionality overlap, so when should I be choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope these links helps you

1. [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin)
2. [Is MEF a replacement for System.Addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124040/is-mef-a-replacement-for-system-addin)
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2008/06/13/mafmef.aspx