# Unable to get preloaded assembly with Assembly.Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, assemblies

I am preloading an assembly in the Application_Start() using Assembly.LoadFrom("pathtomyassembly").

Why am I not able to get my assembly using Assembly.Load("MyAssemblyName") just like I can with any other assembly loaded automatically from the bin directory.

Is there a way to do this without calling LoadFrom() with the assembly path every time?

**UPDATE:**

The weird thing is, when I use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

I can see that my assembly is loaded in the AppDomain.

Is there a way to get it without looping through the assemblies?

Comment: can you show some code and explain why you load them manually instead of referencing them in the project?

Comment: @Davide Piras: There is not much code to show. I use Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath) at runtime and I then need to instanciate some custom classes from those assemblies on demand. Basically, I have a common code base running as a child application under each of my custom application. When I call a webpage from this "base" application, I need to be able to access a class from my custom assembly.

Comment: so you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803540/load-assembly-at-runtime-and-create-class-instance ??

Comment: @Davide Piras: Activator.CreateInstance with the class name and the assembly does not seem to work either. I works fine when I create an instance of a class from the assemblies in my bin folder, but not with the ones I load dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looping through AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() to get my assembly.

```
public static Assembly GetAssemblyFromAppDomain(string assemblyName)
{
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        if (assembly.FullName.StartsWith(assemblyName + ",")) 
        {
            return assembly;
        }
    }
    return null;   
}
```

Everything seems to work fine.

Comment: try  fully qualified name in Assembly.Load(). check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to supply fully qualified name `Assembly.Load [Assembly].Load("Assembly text name, Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken")`.

E.g.

```
Assembly.Load("ActivityLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

Ref:

http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2010/02/16/137988.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you can't use `Assembly.Load("MyAssemblyName")` because there's no matching DLL in your program's bin directory.  Your build script would need to manually copy that DLL from `pathtomyassembly` to your program's bin directory, or you'd need to add it as a link in your solution and make sure "Copy to Output Directory" is checked.