# How get reflection info of a class loaded in the main assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm using the [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) function to get reflection info about a class. if I use that function from my app all works ok, but now i need to call that function from an external dll previously loaded from my app.

This code works fine if the called from the main app

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyType");
```

but fails (*myType1* returns nothing) if that code is put inside of a dll (that dll is loaded from my app)

The question is how i can use `Type.GetType` to load a type which exist in the Exe which load the dll?

**EDIT :**

I think which the question can be reformulated like
 how i can load a type from the assembly which loads my dll?

```
MyEXE
  Myclass   
  MyDll (loaded by MyExe)
    Type.GetType //only get types of the MyDll assembly, how i can access the Myclass type which is defined on MyExe?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803540/load-assembly-at-runtime-and-create-class-instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Fully Qualified Names when using DLL's outside of the project scope

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("MyType, MyNameSpace", true, true);
```

Give that a try

Comment: Please check the updated anwser , I really I'm using qualified names, the issue is that when I use the `Type.GetType` function only get types of the current assembly (MyDll) and i need get the type from the exe which loads the assembly.

Comment: Your example says that your not using fully qualified namespace. Look at the example again to make sure your using a , to separate your class name from namespace

Comment: Thanks very much i missed the `,`

Comment: I should have used the code wrap to make it more apparent. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

you can also load the Assemblies via the Assembly.Load Method, and then enumerate all (GetTypes()) or also get a specific type from the assembly. just take a look at the Assembly class