# loading dll at run time in .Net and create a class

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to load a dll from another applications at run time but at the same time, I need to create an instance of a class implemented in the dll. Could it be done? I could load dlls at run time and there are some examples for them but how could I call a class without the dll being loaded? Won't compile, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Load Assembly at runtime and create class instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803540/load-assembly-at-runtime-and-create-class-instance)

Comment: [How to: Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx)

Comment: [How to: Unload an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a dll in runtime.

like this:

```
//load assembly
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("ADll.dll");

//get types from assembly
var typesInAssembly = assembly.GetTypes();

var type = typesInAssembly.First(/*select one*/);

//create instance
var object = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object [] { "arguments" });
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you call the properties of the new object? can not use object.MyProperty, right?

Comment: Of course you can same way as call method below. Just use GetProperties

Comment: One more question, if the dll being loaded needs another dll, could I load multiple dlls the same time? It does not seem working....

Comment: If that dll is in the same directory it should find it automagically. If it doesn't have a look at the basedir of your current `AppDomain`.

Answer (score 1):

It will compile. The easiest way is to have common interface with your app and loaded dll. Hot to do this you can find here: [C# - Correct Way to Load Assembly, Find Class and Call Run() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-sharp-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method).

But if you do not have common interface still you can `CreateInstance`, then find all method you need (below example is for all methods):

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = Type.GetType(selectedObjcClass) .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

And then call selected one using `Invoke` like this:

```
method.Invoke(selectedObjcClass, params...);
```