# Can I use different namespace as variable depending on the configuration?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

For example, I have two namespaces, provided by other dlls. and cannot be modified.

```
namespace A_Build 
{
   public class D {}
   public class E {}
}
namespace A_Test 
{
   public class D {}
   public class E {}
}
```

There is also a method that need to be designed to returns an object dynamically.

```
public dynamic get_D()
{
    string stage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stage"];

    if(stage = "Build")
    {
        return new A_Build.D();
    }
    if(stage = "Test")
    {
        return new A_Test.D();
    }
    return object;
}
```

Since there will be a lot of constructor `A_{stage}.D()`
I want the namespace to act like a variable to make code more cleaner.

For example

```
if(stage = "Build")
{
    using A = A_Build;
}
if(stage = "Test")
{
    using A = A_Test;
}    
public dynamic get_D()
{
    return new A.D();
}
```

How could I fix the syntax to achieved my desired result.

Comment: If you're able to decide at compile time, maybe you could use preprocessor directives?

Comment: You can load assembly (dll) and create an instance of your object something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1803881/754438

Comment: have you thought about doing this with Dependency injection? then just injecting the service you need based on a check.  That way you just inherit from the same interface.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a delegate. Something like this:

```
Func<dynamic> newObject;
if (stage == "Build")
{
    newObject = () => new A_Build.D();
}
if (stage == "Test")
{
    newObject = () => new A_Test.D();
}
return newObject();
```