# How to access the classes from a namespace which is included in another project

Tags: reference

I am having 3 projects namely Pro1, Pro2 and Pro3.

I have added the reference of Pro3 into Pro2 and Pro2 into Pro1.

Now my question is how to access the classes of Pro3 from Pro1. I did not added the reference of Pro3 but added the reference Pro2 which has the reference of Pro3.

Can i access the Pro3 classes from Pro1 which has the reference of Pro2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is on C# based on your other questions.

Direct answer is No, you cannot acces Pro3 classes in Pro1 without referencing it. Transitivity doesn't apply in project references.

Having said that if you still want to do it you have got few options here:
[MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290650/use-classes-from-another-mef-assembly-without-referencing-to-it),
[Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do that. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html