# Can I get a reference to an object contained in an assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I thought I can get an reference to an object contained in the EXE if I load the .net assembly(which is an exe) into my own appdomain and get the object reference through refleciton.

Can I really do this?

Here is my sample code...

```
myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyAppDomain");
myDomain.ExecuteAssembly(exePath);

Assembly myAssembly = myDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(a => a.FullName.Contains("TestAssembly"));

Type t = commandsAssembly.GetType("TestClass");
```

By any way can I get a reference to an object of this type?

Edit:
In the main method of my EXE I am creating an object of type TestClass, I want a reference to that object. What I thought is ExecuteAssembly will execute the exe in the new appdomain, so when the EXE is instantiated my object would be created. Please correct me if I am wrong. CreateInstance will create a new object but I want reference to my object which gets created when EXE is executed... May be I am thinking in a stupid way, please correct me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ExecuteAssembly doesn't come back beforde the end of the Main method... will your TestClass reference be still there or already disposed ? Please explain more clearly why you want to do what you describe.

Comment: Yahia@ This is just sample code, i shall call ExecuteAssembly in another thread and shall use the myDomain, to get the references to the real objects running in that domain. I thought if I can create a mini framework to do UI Test automation. To be straightforward, I want to grab all the living instances of a type in an appdomain.

Comment: see my edit... if you really need to do this there are options, you would "just" need to do what a good (memory) profiler has to do - at least as a starting point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `commandsAssembly.CreateInstance ("TestClass");` or `Activator.CreateInstance (t);`

**EDIT - after the addition that all living instances are of interest:**

I think the only to achieve this is to write some sort of "debugger" which is really a tough call... some potentially usefull links

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032249/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released/)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122592/Writing-a-NET-debugger-part-1-Starting-the-debuggi 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122591/Writing-a-NET-debugger-part-2-Handling-events-and 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126142/Writing-a-net-debugger-part-3-symbol-and-source-fi 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132798/Writing-a-NET-debugger-part-4-breakpoints 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx

The CLR profiler needs to do parts of you want - source is available so perhaps a good start...

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this kind of stuff. I shall go through your links and work on my stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way:

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, [constructorArg1, ...]);
```

It assumes a public constructor on the type.

Comment: In the main method of my EXE I am creating an object of type TestClass, I want a reference to that object. What I thought is ExecuteAssembly will execute the exe in the new appdomain, so when the EXE is instantiated my object would be created. Please correct me if I am wrong. CreateInstance will create a new object but I want reference to my object which gets created when EXE is executed...

Comment: @coolcake hm, that's a bit weird. you would need a handle to some root object in the AppDomain and recursively search through the graph to find the reference you want.

Comment: Thanks alot Rex, thinking that there is just a simple class, how can I get a reference to it? Can't I use get type and retrieve it?

Comment: @coolcake without some pretty sophisticated trickery (way beyond normal reflection) I don't know of any way to simply "grab all the living instances of a type in an appdomain"

Comment: Thanks for making me clear. Thats what my question. So I cannot get living instances of a type in an appdomain... I thought I may get it by some way... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("[AssemblyName].LoadClass, [AssemblyName]", true));
```

Also look at this for a good discussion: [C# - Correct Way to Load Assembly, Find Class and Call Run() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method)