# Export or execute a console application form project

Tags: c#

How do you save your console application as exe program?
I have found the exe file within the Debug folder, but returns an error when executed.

Error message –

> Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I’m using the Ionic library, I think I need to package the whole program, not sure how to do this?

Comment: What research have you done on the error message?  How has it not helped you?  Please include links and a specific explanation for each detailing why it didn't answer your question.

Comment: [Referencing a 3rd party assembly which is not located in the root location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10055670/669576)

Comment: *"console application as exe program"* - [direct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11523641/1997232), but it may suffice in your case to simply copy complete `Bin` folder.

Answer (score -1):

- Right click on the your project on the solution explorer
- On configuration choose release
- Now you will find a release folder next
  to the debug folder use the .exe inside it