# Validate file by specific thing

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, dll

So I need to check a bunch  of files for valid files my program can use. My file is a dll file but a specific one that only my program can use.  I need to make sure if one of the files is a specific file. 
An extension check is not enough. 
How can I validate it? 
I need to check the file for a specific thing like a string/class. What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Do you need to check that the file is a DLL, that it's a DLL that exposes a certain interface, or that's it's a specific file?

Comment: Dynamically load the assembly and check if the needed class exists, for example try to create an instance of it, and handle accordingly.

Comment: @user3553031: I need to check if the file is a valid dll file for my program.

Comment: @Khaykin: That sounds pretty good for me,  how would I perform such a check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-sharp-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method shows you all method needed (and also potentially necessary code to deal with unloading).

Comment: here is another thought calculate `MD5` of those files and store some where in the program and then during run time calculate `md5` of the dll's and compare