# How to load dlls from a NuGet into the current AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, nuget

I try to create a modulable system in which each module can depend on other ones. Each module is a NuGet and their dependencies have to be resolved via NuGet. Each module contains a Type which will implements an shared Interface which allow for extracting a list of instruction.

All these instructions are to be executed in reverse order.

#### The detailed situation is this:

1. I have 4 projects which I will call `API`, `S`, `M1`, `M2`. They are all NuGets and they depends one from another is that way (`->` stands for 'depends on'): `S -> API`, `M1 -> S`, `M2 -> M1`.
2. On the other hand we have the projet `CORE`, `CONSOLE` and `TESTS`. They aren't NuGets but they references each others in this way (`->` stands for 'references'): `CORE -> S`, `CONSOLE -> CORE`, `TESTS -> CORE`.
3. M1 et M2 are modules, once again they are special because they contains a Type which must be found and instantiated from within CORE.

#### The goal is this:

1. I must fetch and install locally NuGets from a given repository.

   - This is done, it fetch the NuGets, unzip them into a given location.
2. I must inject the dlls from this extraction into the installer as if they were some sort of plugins.

   - How do I inject the correct dlls from the imported NuGets knowing that:

     1. some of them are already present in the project `CORE` (notably the dlls that are present in the projects `API` and `S`).
     2. some of them contain copies of the dll for different .NET Frameworks.
     3. when I succeed to inject the dlls (by some artificial processes of filtering the `lib/whateverframework` directories and I try to find all the types which have a specific Attribute (which is located in the shared project `API`), this attribute seems to be different if I use the one which is in the dlls from NuGet and the one which I can directly use in VS.

I use C# 6 and VS2015.

How could I load dlls into the running application with **all its dependencies** using **NuGet core API** to solve dependencies? What is the **best/proper** way to do this?

Comment: This is a bit broad... Do you have a more specific question that just generally "how do I do this?"

Comment: I edited my post to ask a more specific question... I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers happened to be a good solution to me...

Comment: You should look at MEF for injecting the DLL's or types.  I'm not sure NuGet is the correct tool for this; it kinda depends on what you want to do.  NuGet is oriented for public consumption, so if you're not distributing the DLLs to the public, it's a bit overkill.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1137781/102937

Comment: I will actually distribute the modules to the public eventually... that's the reason why I need NuGet. And plus I need to resolve dependency so I want to use NuGet to do that. But except from this I would like to use some tool to take the dlls I imported with NuGet and inject them into the current application... which will go through the types and fetch the ones which have a specific attribute.

Comment: See MEF and the SO post I linked.  You might not need MEF; you might just need `Activator.CreateInstance()`.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

A sample code you could use:

```
var localRepository = new SharedPackageRepository(packagesPath);
var allAssemblies = localRepository
            .GetPackages()
            .ToArray()
            .SelectMany(p => p.AssemblyReferences.Select(a =>
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(packagesPath, p.Id + "." + p.Version, a.Path);
                var aname = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);
                return new { key = aname.FullName, value = path };
            }))
            .DistinctBy(i => i.key)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.key, i => i.value);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            var aname = new AssemblyName(eventArgs.Name);
            if (allAssemblies.ContainsKey(aname.FullName))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(allAssemblies[aname.FullName]);
            }
            return null;
        };
```