# Assembly.GetTypes() returning null while dynamic loading assembly

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic-programming

I am trying to generate the proxyclass of wcf service at runtime .
I access the SVC url by appending "?wsdl'.
Generate the proxy using ServiceDiscription importer class.

I am able to generate the proxy but not able to access the types in the assembly.

Here is my code:

```
if(_proxyAssembly != null)
{ 
     foreach (Type t in _proxyAssembly.GetTypes())
     {
       //Some coding
     }
}
```

GetTypes() should return all the types in the proxyAssembly class but it is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even attempt to create your own proxy generator magic here and rather use the built-in ChannelFactory for what you want.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/channel-factory-in-wcf/
http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/wcf/difference-between-wcf-proxy-and-channel-factory

Also, you will need to move all the types and interfaces that your client needs to have access to into a separate assembly which will then be shared between the client and the server through standard references. So, again, you don't need to deal with reflection to access those types.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment below, I would suggest you use [Process.Start](https://www.dotnetperls.com/process) to call [SvcUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/generating-a-wcf-client-from-service-metadata) at runtime, have it generate the proxy class, [compile](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime) it into an assembly and [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-sharp-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method) it at runtime. This way you should be able to access all types properly through reflection, pretty much the way you did it in your example.

Comment: Yes , but the issue here is  they will supply  the url only at runtime .for using channel factory I  I need contract details  . And I have to create an application which will be able to generate the proxy at runtime and invoke the method for testing.

Comment: i am not sure how we can generate proxy at run time using svcutil  ,do you have any sample for that ?and this test client should be generic it should take any service URL and and invoke its methods.

Comment: You can use Process.Start() to call svcutil with the right parameters for your case.