# Best way to create a plugin environment in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, plugins

I read this aricle [How to load plugins in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278/how-to-load-plugins-in-net), and I really don't see the brilliance of Microsoft's System.Addin namespace. Why can't I just have a plugins folder in my bin directory that users can put an assembly into that implements an interface I design?  I could then just use reflection to create an instance of the plugin class and reference it with my interface.

Why is the System.Addin way apparently so much better? Especially since it seems like three times the work and a less intuitive design.

Comment: Try to look at http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Overview&referringTitle=Home

Comment: :) you better listen what ppl saying if they say it synchronously

Comment: @Reed Copsey already fixed :) damn spell checker

Comment: @qrow: Again, how do you say something and NOT say it synchronously?  (Did you mean concurrently?)

Comment: @Reed Copsey http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/ second bullet point

Comment: @qrow: Ahh, was thinking it was a joke relating to programming terminology.  Not trying to correct grammer, but help educate for programming related issues only ;)  I apologize if it came across incorrectly.

Comment: @Reed Copsey it's good that my bad english sounds like jokes :)

Comment: @qrow @reed I am glad that my question could contribute to quality nerd humor for generations to come. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"so much better" always depends on your point of view and requirements. If your approach fits your needs, go for it. But plugins can become very fast much more complicated. What about dependencies between plugins? Security? Different schemata how to find plugins? ...? Those kind of features are already solved for you. If you don't need them, a library might be overkill. If you need them, it would be a bad idea to reinvent the wheel. ;-)

Comment: +1 for answering the crux of the question; MEF is a wonderful tool, but it's definitely not a full 'plug-in' framework, with AppDomain isolation, security, and versioning/dependency management.  These additional features are usually over-kill for a simple application, but they are important considerations if you're building a large, mission-critical application.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend looking at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (which was added to the core framework in .NET 4).  It allows you to do exactly what you're describing, and is very simple and flexible to use in extensibility scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for this by the way, I'll be using MEF.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/), that question is from 2008

Comment: I can't believe there actually are THREE duplicate answers and they're all upvoted lol

Comment: They all were posted at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Look at Microsoft's [Managed Extensibilty Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/); the code is open sourced so you could use it a basis to write your own, or you could just use MEF directly.