# .NET Managed equivalent of COM Component Categories?

Tags: .net, plugins, components

Does .NET have a canonical mechanism to register related objects? (I.e. component categories for .NET?)

## Background

If you have a bunch of COM objects, that are all related, and all implement the same interfaces, and want a central place to register all these objects, you use **Component Categories**.

```
HKCR\Component Categories
```

Is **the** place where you can register a bunch of related COM objects. If my software supports plug-ins, i would create a *"category"*, e.g.:

```
HKCR\Component Categories\{1628B80E-E735-481C-8EDA-FC13D92B5F36}
   409: REG_SZ = "Ian's super-cool application plugins"
```

Then anyone who wants to register their plugin with my application just has to mention that they implement the category by creating an entry called **Implemented Categories**:

```
HKCR\{EC05174F-F824-4888-9FDC-EE33080917DE}
   \ProgID
       default = "Stackoverflow.IansSuperCoolApp.1"
   \Implemented Categories
       \{1628B80E-E735-481C-8EDA-FC13D92B5F36}
```

And now i know where to find them. Microsoft, for example, has a few dozen image transform filters all registered under category `{C501EDBE-9E70-11D1-9053-00C04FD9189D}`:

- DXImageTransform.Microsoft.CrBlinds.1
- DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Iris.1
- DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader.1
- DXImageTransform.Microsoft.RadialWipe.1
- ...

There's also shell extensions, SQL Server conflict resolvers; any time you need a way to find all classes that you want.

## Just one implementation

Now, there's nothing *special* about `Component Categories`, other than it being the canonical place to register related COM objects. Everyone is free to create their own way of registering classes. But the guys who invented COM decided to create *"the"* place to do it. Microsoft even provides [an API to help using it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But nothing stops me from declaring my own mechanism to register classes that contain functionality i want:

- i could create my own `HKCR\Ian's Supercool Application plugins`
- i could have an XML file that declares ProgIDs

If if you're going to be registering COM objects in a group, why not use the place that was designed for the task for you.

## But what about .NET?

What happens if i have a few dozen .NET assemblies (*.dll); what should i do to register those? i can't *really* use COM Component categories, because these are not COM objects (i.e. they are not COM objects or COM callable wrappers); they are managed assemblies.

Is there a canonical mechanism in .NET to register assembly categories?

**Note:** You can stop reading everything after the first line; the rest is just fluff.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, then the answer is that .NET is meant to be a different beast than COM objects.  The mechanism you're talking about for a central place if storage of COM objects is part of what led us to the [DLL Hell that .NET was designed to eliminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973843.aspx).  It's something to be avoided, not duplicated.

That said, in [.NET you can add items to the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx).  And the guidelines for doing so including ***grouping your code into Namespaces that simply make sense***.  Microsoft offers guidance for this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042(v=vs.100).aspx.  That ***is*** the canonical way to organize your code libraries.

From the article that tells you how to use the GAC:

> It is recommended that you only use the GAC for your own assemblies
>   when it is absolutely necessary. Microsoft suggests that you should
>   generally keep your assemblies within the application folder.

More often than not, however, the best bet is to ***not*** use the Global Assembly Cache, and just have your .dll files copied in with the application.  This helps avoid the DLL Hell situation that was the bane of Microsoft platform developers before .NET.

Comment: So if a third party creates an assembly dll; as long as they declare their class in the `namespace IansSuperCoolPlugin`, my application will be able to find that assembly? If i created an assembly, with a class in the `Microsoft.Flight.Simulator.X.Plugin` namespace, their executable will be able to find my assembly? That seems odd; i wouldn't think that an application would iterate over ***every*** assembly sitting in the global assembly cache.

Comment: i guess the tricky part comes from, "grouping your code into Namespaces that simply make sense" - it's not **my** code. It's someone else's code; that is sitting in a dll that i've never seen, that suddenly has appeared on the client computer. **Update**: i see the problem: ***"The mechanism you're talking about for a central place if storage of COM objects"*** That's exactly not what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the question was to create plugins.

Since .NET has no way to register dlls, the best technique is to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282/12597), where you load all DLLs you can find. Iterate all types in the assembly, looking for interesting ones.

In .NET 3.5, Microsoft formalized this technique into an extraordinarily complicated [`System.Addins`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384171(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.