# MEF equivalent for .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mef

As the title says, is there any MEF equivalent for .NET Framework 3.5?

I'm doing something that requires code to be in .NET Framework 3.5, and I'd like to have a plugin framework that loads DLLs that were made using later versions of .NET or even made in other programming languages. Is there a way to make a .NET 3.5 program/library load DLLs from a specific folder and instantiate them and interact with them?

EDIT: Just an FYI. The .NET 3.5 thing I am working with uses a special mscorlib dll that has some features removed, such as System.IO, and I can't replace said dll or else the thing will break.

Comment: Hi! Not a fully formed answer, but dynamic assembly loading is possible in .NET 3.5 as well ([Assembly.Load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-3.5) and [Assembly.LoadFrom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-3.5)), and there were approaches to creating plugins there as well. I don't remember if there were any popular frameworks or libraries though, it's been forever since I worked on 3.5. But yeah, Definitely possible to dynamically load assemblies from a plugins folder.

Comment: `System.AddIn` is available in .NET 3.5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb384241(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN (though I've never used it and don't know if it's actually good) - your question might already be answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278/how-to-load-plugins-in-net).

Comment: Please read the edit I forgot to make (sorry). The thing I am working with uses a special version of mscorlib that doesn't have System.IO.GetFiles, which is what System.AddIn relies on, unfortunately. Hence why I made this question as this is a difficult thing to figure out.